# How to add an autorole to a member after voting on discord bot list

Tags: automation, discord

I added my server to discord bot list and I want to find a bot to automatically add a role after voting. Is there a known bot to do this?

I tried using the vote tracker bot but I couldn't get the links it sent me to work properly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.